# Table alias and datatables

Tags: crystal-reports

I am triying to fill a report with datatables. The report has two tables  which are 
he same but with diferent alias. In c# I create a datatable for one of them with the records that must be shown and another datatable with the other table info. Crystal only gets info from the first datatable to fill the two tables so the shown data is wrong. Can I fill the two tables that are the same but diferent alias with two diferent datatables?

This is the same problem that I wrote yesterday but simplier.

Thanks for all,

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports does support duplicate tables with aliases. 
The problem may be the link. If your trying to display the two tables on the report both there's no JOIN or WHERE statement.

The table would need a link with itself. Here's a link to a [tutorial](http://www.wellho.net/forum/The-MySQL-Relational-Database/Joining-a-table-to-itself.html) on join a table to itself

```
select * from tbl1 as child join tbl1 as parent on parent.primarykey = child.foreignkey;
```